# Is there a way to configure whitelisted websites via terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, parental-controls

We currently have parental controls configured on our company Macs that we deploy however it looks like the option for parental control is greyed out and there is a website that is being blocked that shouldn't be

Is there a way of configuring whitelisted sites via the terminal as there isn't a way of using the GUI to do it right now

Answer (score 4):

First, convert the `com.apple.familycontrols.contentfilter.plist` to XML.

```
 sudo plutil -convert xml1 /Library/Managed\ Preferences/yourUsername/com.apple.familycontrols.contentfilter.plist
```

Then, edit the XML file and remove the site that you want to remove

```
sudo nano /Library/Managed\ Preferences/yourUsername/com.apple.familycontrols.contentfilter.plist
```

This should help you.

Comment: What if i want to add a site to whitelist? rather than remove from a blacklist?

Comment: It has both options for FilterWhitelist and FilterBlacklist. You can modify as per your need.

Comment: When prompted for a password would i need the local admin or the users password in this instance?

Comment: you can go with your user password if it is admin of the machine. 
Else, local admin

Comment: @udhy `sudo` always asks for the password of the current user, and will fail if the current user isn't an admin user (at least in the default installation).

Comment: @Udhy Thanks for this very enlightening answer!  I was able to use it to work around a bug I encountered after upgrading to Sonoma.