# Screen Time broken by Sonoma

Tags: screen-time, sonoma

I have a simple list of approved websites configured on a regular (non-admin) user for my kid.  For various reasons I don’t want to set this up using Family Sharing, just the Screen Time settings for the user account.

Prior to Sonoma, this was working fairly well, although I did notice that the allowlist didn’t block non-Safari browsers like Chrome/Opera.

Since updating to Sonoma, this seems to have been hardened somewhat as I initially got spammed with Screen Time network restriction messages for many apps, including News and Weather widgets.

A handful of times I used the passcode to whitelist these requests.  I also had to go in to the allowlist manually to add some related websites.  But now the Screen Time control panel is broken in several ways:

1. Although Safari still restricting existing websites as expected, the pop-up selecting between “Unrestricted Access”, “Limit Adult Websites” and “Allowed Websites Only” is stuck at “Unrestricted Access”.  Attempting to change this asks for the ScreenTime passcode but then flips back to Unrestricted.
2. Since the button to edit the list of “Allowed Websites” is only displayed in restricted mode, this makes the list completely inaccessible.
3. Possibly related: changes to the Downtime schedule are also being ignored, displaying one time in Settings but always activating on the pre-Sonoma schedule.

My guess is that the control panel is reverting to some default view because it is unable to parse the current settings.

Where are Screen Time settings stored and how might I repair them or at least reset them?

UPDATE: After a few newer point updates, the situation is significantly worse:

- No Safari web sites are blocked at all, regardless of the filter settings
- All web sites are blocked in other browsers, even those that are explicitly whitelisted

Comment: This answer gave me enough to at least edit the whitelist: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/371030/241982.  But all the symptoms are still there.  I don't know where to find the Downtime schedule.